# Convert this var to a list of longs?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, .net-4.0

I have a screen attached here and I need to know how I can convert the list to a list of Longs?

```
var x = SchedulerMatrixStorage.Resources.Items.Select(col => col.Id);
```

Where, Id is of type `Object`

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your list appears to be homogenous, you can take advantage of the built-in conversion functions that are part of the .NET framework:

```
var x = SchedulerMatrixStorage.Resources.Items
       .Select(col => Convert.ToInt64(col.Id)).ToList();
```

The `Convert` static class provides several conversion functions, one group of which will convert objects of various types to various built-in value types, like `long`. Most of these functions also have an overload that takes an `object` parameter (which I'm assuming is what your collection fundamentally contains).

Note that this function will fail at runtime if the supplied object is something that can't be converted into a `long` (such as if you were to pass in, say, a `Form`), but judging by your screenshot this should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`long.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b6b4bx3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in your `Select` statement, since from your screenshot it looks like values in the `Items` collection could be strings:

```
var x = SchedulerMatrixStorage.Resources.Items.Select(col => 
   long.Parse(col.Id.ToString())).ToList();
```

`x` will be resolved to type `System.Collections.Generic.List<long>`.

Comment: Why `Parse`? I think it was object, not a string.

Comment: What's the advantage of `Parse` over `Cast` if all objects are of type `long` anyway?

Comment: @gaearon His first item is: `"-1"`, which is a string.

Comment: This will fail for his data, as only the first item (in his displayed list) is a string. The other casts would fail.

Comment: @Adam Good point. Edited to use `ToString()` instead of a cast; however TBH I like your use of `Convert.ToInt64` better.

Comment: @gaearon There is no method named `Convert.ToLong`; however the type `long` is equivalent to the `System.Int64` .NET Framework Type. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk(v=vs.71).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If `Id` is of type `object` but the value is always a string, you could use:

```
var x = SchedulerMatrixStorage.Resources
                              .Items
                              .Select(col => long.Parse((string)col.Id)
                              .ToList();
```

However, it's not clear that the result always *is* a string. You need to give us more information about `col.Id`.

In general, you want something like this:

```
var x = SchedulerMatrixStorage.Resources
                              .Items
                              .Select(ConvertColumnId)
                              .ToList();

private static long ConvertColumnId(object id)
{
    // Do whatever it takes to convert `id` to a long here... for example:
    if (id is long)
    {
        return (long) id;
    }
    if (id is int)
    {
        return (int) id;
    }
    string stringId = id as string;
    if (stringId != null)
    {
        return long.Parse(stringId);
    }
    throw new ArgumentException("Don't know how to convert " + id +
                                " to a long");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think this should do what you want

```
var x = SchedulerMatrixStorage.Resources.Items.Select(col => col.Id).Cast<long>().ToList();
```

Comment: As with the similar answer, this would fail for him. His very first item is a string.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the quickest way is this:

```
var x = SchedulerMatrixStorage.Resources.Items.Select(col => col.Id).Cast<long>();
```

although you should really make sure you've only got Id's that are long before they were boxed as an object.

Comment: This would fail with his supplied values, since the first one is a string.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed to convert the first string `"-1"` to a proper long. The line `var x = SchedulerMatrixStorage.Resources.Items.Select(col => Convert.ToInt64(col.Id)).ToList();` work perfectly for me now. The Id will always be a long. With that rule assured, is there a best method to accomplish this? I mean, my task is done but wanted to now if LINQ offer an even better method...

[image]

Comment: You cannot ask a new question when you're posting an answer. Nobody gets notifications when you post an answer, so nobody will see this. Ask a new question, or add a comment to somebody's answer mentioning his name, like this: @Hassan.